# Uploaded image not able to view in Amazon s3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I uploaded the image to Amazon S3 Successfully but when I view the image it shows nothing.

My View :

```
public JsonResult Upload(SocialJobMediaModel socialJobMediaModel)
        { 
            var imagePathErrorMessage = new ImagePathErrorMessage();
            if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            { 
                _log = GetProcessorLogger("CompanyXcodes", "CompanyXcodes", 1);
                StageMediaFileProcessor stageMediaFileProcessor = new StageMediaFileProcessor(_log);
                imagePathErrorMessage = stageMediaFileProcessor.UploadMediaFilesToS3(Request.Files[0].InputStream, Request.Files[0].FileName,"1234");
            }
}




public void BulkUpload(Stream stream, string fileName, NameValueCollection metadata, ILogger log = null)
        {
            // Prepare request

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AwsRegion))
        {
            Client = new AmazonS3Client(_awsAccessKey, _awsSecretKey);
        }
        else
        {
            var regionEndPoint = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(AwsRegion);
            Client = new AmazonS3Client(regionEndPoint);
        }

            var tu = new TransferUtility(Client); 

            var request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
            {           
                InputStream = stream,
                Key = KeyPath + fileName,
                BucketName = BucketName,
                CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead,
            };

            if (metadata != null)
            {
                foreach (var metaDataKey in metadata.AllKeys)
                {
                    request.Metadata.Add(metaDataKey, metadata[metaDataKey]);
                }
            }

            // Set up progress logging (if logger provided)
            if (log != null)
                request.UploadProgressEvent += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.PercentDone % 10 == 0)
                        log.LogInfo("Uploaded {0} of {1} bytes ({2} %)", e.TransferredBytes, e.TotalBytes, e.PercentDone);
                };

            // Upload (synchronous)
            tu.Upload(request); 

        }
```

I am able to upload the image Successfully but when I view the image it shows nothing.can any one help me on this

I tried to upload filepath instead of inputstream but it throws the error

Comment: what is the s3-key of the uploaded file?

Comment: I have a valid key auth.